# ¿En que momento usar "VAR" en javascript y por que es necesario?

Tags: javascript

Tengo una duda, siempre he codificado en js pero siempre no usaba el var para anteponer en la declaración de una variable pero vi que algunos dicen que se debe poner var dentro de una función, otros dicen que se pone cuando esta fuera.

Gracias por sus aportes.

Comment: Quizás sea por el ámbito de la variable si no usas var para declarar una variable esta sera global. Lo cual es una mala practica.

Answer (score 2):

Depende de la version de javascript.

Si usas JS5 (lo estandar en navegadores) `var` es la *keyword* utilizada para declarar una variable. Ej:

```
var miVariable, otraVariableInicializada=1, 
    otraVariableUndefined;
```

Ahora si usas Javascript 6 (ECMAScript 2015) o superior (NodeJS), la keyword `var` tiene menos usos.

En general se pefiere el uso de `const` (para constantes y funciones) o `let` (para variables) salvo que se necesite crear un [closure](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/607/c%C3%B3mo-funcionan-las-clausuras-en-javascript), en cuyo caso se debe utilizar `var`.

```
const modulo = require('modulo');

const miFunc = () => {
    var enClousure = 1234;

    return () => {
       let valorLocal = modulo.getAlgo();
       return enClousure + valorLocal;
    }; 

};
```

Comment: Cuando te refieres a node.. No me queda claro desde que versión de `node` puedo usar `const` o `let`

Answer (score 1):

Aquí te dejo un ejemplo que me dio mi profesor en su día para ver si lo entiendes.

```js
function f1(a,b){
    var c=c+a; // La variable c es LOCAL
    d=d+b; // La variable d es GLOBAL
    document.write("En f1()<br/>");
    document.write("c="+c+"<br/>");
    document.write("d="+d+"<br/>");
}

function f2(){
    document.write("En f2()<br/>");
    document.write("c="+c+"<br/>");
    document.write("d="+d+"<br/>");    
}


// ---------------------------------------

var c = 10; // Variable GLOBAL. Es un script
d = 20; // Variable GLOBAL

f1(1,2);
f2();
```

Comment: Buen ejemplo +1... Aunque una pequeña descripción de lo que sucede creo que ayudaría mucho a un ojo menos experimentado

Answer (score 0):

Cuando tu declaras una `variable` sin poner el `var` delante, estas declarando esa `variable`de manera global a todo el documento `*.js` en cambio si pones `var variable` la estas declarando local al metodo que vas a utilizar.

Comment: Esta respuesta es érronea, las variables definidas mediante el tipo `var` también son globales y pueden ser accedidas mediante el objeto `window`

Answer (score 0):

Si colocas `var` la puedes usar dentro de pero no fuera de donde se declaro; [Ejemplo](https://jsfiddle.net/Roberto_LO/1vhd5582/2/) como un nombre de variable se comporta dependiendo donde fue declarada; incluso la declarada sin "var" dentro de la función queda global a la página.