# ¿Como funciona este slider hecho en Javascript puro?

Tags: javascript, css, scroll, slider

Lo que quiero hacer es un menu fixed. Cuando clickeo en el menu se active el slider. 
Pero no entiendo este codigo:

```js
function funcion(){
 var page = document.getElementById('page');
 var sections = page.getElementsByTagName('section'); 
 // This transition can be defined in the CSS if preferred.
 var transition = 'top .8s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1)';
 page.style.transition = transition;
 page.onclick = slideDown;
 //document.getElementsByClassName("")

 function slideDown(e) {  
  // Delegate.
  if (e.target.className != 'next') {
   return;
  }

  // Prevent firing simultaneously.
  page.onclick = '';  
  self = e.target.parentNode; // Devuelve el elemento <section>.
  var offset = self.getBoundingClientRect(); // Devuelve tamñano y posicion relativa a la ventana.
  var scroll = self.offsetTop; // La distancia desde la parte superior de <section> con su padre (<div id=page>).

  // CSS Transition slide.
  page.style.top = (-offset.height-offset.top) + 'px'; // La altura del elemento (-offset) menos la parte mas alta de la pagina.

  setTimeout(function () {
   // Reposition the real scrollbar.
   page.style.transition = 'none';
   page.style.top = '';
   window.scrollTo(0, offset.height+scroll);
   page.style.transition = transition;
   // Reattach event.
   page.onclick = slideDown;
   // This timeout length should match the CSS animation time (.8s).
  }, 800);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Con este código ya tienes un menú `fixed` que muestra el `slider` con una transición `CSS`, con este código estás haciendo clic sobre un elemento `DOM` con id `'page'`, al hacer clic recojes los elementos `<section>` de ese mismo id y los usas para calcular la distáncia que hay entre el elemento `<section>` y la parte superior de la ventana, con eso aplicas la transición calculada al elemento `'page'` y tras un `timeout` vuelves la transición a su estado inicial

Te dejo el código comentado

```
   function funcion(){
        // Recuperamos el elemento con id 'page'
        var page = document.getElementById('page');
        // Recuperamos todas las etiquetas <section> dentro del elemento 'page'
        var sections = page.getElementsByTagName('section');

        // Definimos la transicion css a aplicar al elemento id 'page'
        var transition = 'top .8s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1)';
        // Aplicamos la transicion como un estilo css
        page.style.transition = transition;
        // Al clicar en el elemento 'page' hacemos la funcion slideDown
        page.onclick = slideDown;

        function slideDown(e) {  
            // Si estamos haciendo click sobre un elemento DOM con clase 'next',
            // no hacemos nada de la funcion slideDown
            if (e.target.className != 'next') {
                return;
            }
            // Prevenimos el doble click
            page.onclick = ''; 
            // Recuperamos el elemento DOM Padre inmediato del elemento que hemos hecho click *(event.target)*
            self = e.target.parentNode; 
            // Cogemos el elemento <section> dentro del padre recuperado.
            var offset = self.getBoundingClientRect(); 
            // Recojemos tamñano y posicion relativa a la ventana,
            // de la distancia desde la parte superior de <section> con su padre (<div id=page>).
            var scroll = self.offsetTop; 

            // Aplicamos la transicion CSS calculando
            // La altura del elemento <section> menos la parte mas alta de la pagina.
            page.style.top = (-offset.height-offset.top) + 'px'; 

            // Con un timeout volvemos la transicion a su estado inicial
            setTimeout(function () {
                // Reposicionar la barra de scroll.
                page.style.transition = 'none';
                page.style.top = '';
                window.scrollTo(0, offset.height+scroll);
                // Reasignamos la transicion inicial
                page.style.transition = transition;
                // Reasignamos el evento onclick.
                page.onclick = slideDown;
                // Este timeout debería de durar parecido a la transicion (8s).
            }, 800);
        }
     }
```

Ya que me lo pediste en un comentario dejo el enlace al JSFiddle aqui con el ejemplo funcionando
https://jsfiddle.net/w0usmrbj/1/

Comment: No entiendo la parte de "recuperamos las secciones del elemento page"..

Comment: Perdón, he cambiado la frase entera, espero que ahora la entiendas mejor

Comment: de todas formas, y aprovechando el post, ¿porque se declaran funciones dentro de functiones?

Comment: Tengo un problema cuando selecciono un  `section ` con `offset =  document.getElementsByTagName("section")[0].getBoundingClientRect();` a este `section` lo reconoce como primero cuando en realidad es el segundo.

Comment: @GDP esto la forma de programar javascript lo permite y el ejemplo mas claro es en el que asignas esta funcion `function()`  al onload de una pagina `<script>window.onload = function;</script>` donde te interesa que esa funcion se carge en el onload de la pagina

Comment: @TOMAS hay que cercionarse de que el `<section>` al que quieres acceder esté dentro del elemento `'page'`, si és así sería de ayuda que nos pasases un ejemplo del codigo que te esta causando eso, en https://jsfiddle.net/ por ejemplo

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/maradona86/w0usmrbj/ ahi lo dejo pero no anda el scroll con JsFiddle...

Comment: he reparado tu problema con el onload, és mejor que uses `window.onload = new funtion() {}` antes que `<body onload="funcion">` con este pequeño cambio a mi me funciona todo, me coge todos los `<section>` sin problema https://jsfiddle.net/w0usmrbj/1/   A mí con firefox si me funciona el scroll

Comment: @GDP Declarar funciones dentro de funciones es muy útil cuando necesitas acceder a variables de la función padre, mira cómo funcionan las [clausuras](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/607/c%C3%B3mo-funcionan-las-clausuras-en-javascript)

Comment: @PabloLozano Estoy acostumbrado a ello en JQuery, pero no sabia que se utilizasen tambien en javascript. Gracias.

Comment: @GDP JQuery es Javascript! No es más que una librería

Comment: @PabloLozano si si, me refiero a que las usas de continuo en JQery tipicas ready, click etc, que ni te das cuenta de que es eso. Me acabais de abrir un mundo jajaja