# Duda acerca de la ejecución de callbacks adheridos a una promesa

Tags: javascript, promesas

> Callbacks will never be called before the completion of the current run of the `JavaScript` event loop.

fuente: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises

En la versión [en español](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Usar_promesas):

> Las funciones callback nunca serán llamadas antes de la terminación de
>   la ejecución actual del bucle de eventos de JavaScript.

¿A qué se refiere con eso de que los callbacks adheridos a una promesa no serán ejecutados antes de que se complete la ejecución actual del event loop? No entiendo muy bien esa parte

Comment: Hola Juan. Creo que si cambias el título de tu pregunta y la modificas no la identificarán como un posible duplicado. Preguntas cómo funcionan las promesas en el título pero en el enunciado, en realidad en lo que tienes duda es en comprender qué es el bucle de eventos de `JavaScript`. Otra cosa que ayuda a hacer _flag_ de tu pregunta es que sitúas otra pregunta después pidiendo algo que es meramente una opinión pero de la que puedes encontrar mucha información en internet y en StackOverflow. Siempre intenta preguntar solo una cosa en cada pregunta.

Comment: Ya modifique el titulo, y también quite la parte que puede estar basada en opiniones

Comment: Relacionada: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/166250/sincron%c3%ada-vs-asincron%c3%ada-para-recoger-datos-en-tiempo-real-con-javascript/243005#243005

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vamos por pasos:

Definamos *callback* brevemente como una función que se pasa como parámetro a otra para que esta segunda la llame. Asumo que el OP conoce el concepto así que no entraremos en detalles.

#### Modelo de concurrencia de Javascript:

- Lo primero de todo es entender que no se puede parar la ejecución del código una vez ésta ha empezado, la ejecución se ejecutará hasta que el código termine de manera normal o provoque un error que no sea capturado. Esto puede provocar que la interfaz de un navegador aparentemente deje de responder a las acciones del usuario, porque esas acciones no obtienen respuesta, ya que el código asociado a dichas acciones pasa a la cola de ejecución, esperando su turno. En resumen, se podría decir que toda ejeción ocurre dentro de un bucle de eventos:

  ```
  while (colaEventos.esperaMensaje()) {
    colaEventos.procesaSiguienteMensaje();
  }
  ```
- Si el hilo actual de ejecución termina, se empezará a ejecutar el siguiente de **la cola de eventos**. Si la cola está vacía, pues no se ejecutará nada y el sistema se quedará a la espera de que algún evento añada código a la cola.

Aquí hemos de aclarar que cuando llamamos a `setTimeout` o `setInterval` no añadimos eventos a la cola directamente, se añadirán los eventos cuando haya pasado el tiempo determinado en las llamadas.

Un ejemplo de código que añade eventos sería la función `setTimeout(callback, time)`: esta función añadirá a la cola de eventos el código de la función `callback` dentro de `time` milisegundos.

```js
let i=1;

while (i < 5) {
  console.log('Añado a la cola de eventos un setTimeout, i vale',i);
  setTimeout(() => console.log(i));
  i++;
}
```

Aquí vemos que vamos encolando llamadas a `console.log()`, pero estas no se ejecutan hasta que el bucle termina. Para cuando el bucle termina `i` vale 5 y por tanto se nos muestra `5` 4 veces, una para cada evento *encolado*.

Este comportamiento es el que tienen las promesas: incluso aunque su ejecución pueda ser completada inmediatamente, el código no se ejecutará hasta que el hilo actual termine. En el ejemplo siguiente vemos que las promesas son *completadas* inmediatamente, pero el código del callback (lo que le pasamos mediante el método *then*), se añade a la cola de eventos:

```js
var i;

for (i=0;i<5;i++) {
   console.log('Creando promesa con i=',i);
   new Promise(function(completa) {
       console.log('Resolviendo para i',i);
       completa(i);
   }).then(resultado => console.log('Obtenemos',resultado));

}
```

**Nota importante**: Al definir una promesa así, tenemos dos callbacks: una es la función `completa`, que se ejecuta de manera síncrona e inmediata, y otra que es la que le pasamos a `then`, que es asíncrona (se añade a la cola del bucle de eventos). Es esta última a la que hace referencia la documentación de la pregunta. Se ve más claro si creamos promesas con **`async`**:

```js
async function creaPromesa(param) {
  return param;
}

let i=0;

for (;i<5;i++) {
  creaPromesa(i).then((dato) => console.log('Resolviendo con', dato));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Primero que todo, es bueno que leas la referencia al [bucle de eventos](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop#Loop_de_eventos) (event loop). Después que lo hayas leído, creo que entenderás perfectamente a qué se refiere si te lo explico con dos snippets:

> **Edición:** En una discusión en meta acerca de esta pregunta salió a relucir [esta otra](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/277690) y es bueno que la consultes también porque las respuestas son muy valiosas.

**Callbacks tradicionales:**

```js
const hazAlgoMas = (numero) => {
  console.log(`se ha llamado a hazAlgoMas con valor: ${numero}`);
  return numero * 2;
}

const hazAlgo = (numero, callback) => {
  console.log(`se ha llamado a hazAlgo con valor: ${numero}`);
  return callback(++numero);
}

for (let i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
  const resultado = hazAlgo(i, hazAlgoMas)
  console.log(`el resultado es: ${resultado}`);
}
```

Observa cómo `hazAlgo` y `hazAlgoMas` se ejecutan una detrás de la otra en cada iteración del ciclo.

**Usando promesas:**

```js
const hazAlgoMas = (numero) => {
  console.log(`se ha llamado a hazAlgoMas con valor: ${numero}`);
  return new Promise(resolve => resolve(numero * 2));
}

const hazAlgo = (numero) => {
  console.log(`se ha llamado a hazAlgo con valor: ${numero}`);
  return new Promise(resolve => resolve(++numero));
}

for (let i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
  hazAlgo(i)
    .then(hazAlgoMas)
    .then(resultado => console.log(`el resultado es: ${resultado}`));
}
```

Como puedes ver, en este caso, el bucle de eventos está organizado de manera diferente, primero en la cola están las llamadas a `hazAlgo`, sin importar que `hazAlgoMas` y el `console.log` están también declarados dentro del ciclo.

Después están las llamadas a `hazAlgoMas` una detrás de la otra y por último todos los `console.log` con los resultados. Como puedes notar, los `callbacks` no han sido ejecutados como en el ejemplo anterior, el ciclo crea diferentes mensajes en el bucle de eventos con llamadas a la función `hazAlgo` y como esta retorna una promesa, los `callbacks` de cada una de estas llamadas se ejecutarán después de que se hayan procesado todos esos mensajes creados anteriormente. Esto es a lo que se refiere el siguiente enunciado:

> los callbacks adheridos a una promesa no serán ejecutados antes de que se complete la ejecución actual del event loop.

Dependiendo de la arquitectura de tu aplicación esto puede ser útil para asegurarte que algún dato no ha cambiado porque algún callback lo ha variado sin que lo desearas.