# Cuantos objetos se han creado?

Tags: java

muy buenas tardes! estoy aprendiendo java, aun muy verde, y he visto este ejercicio por internet que pregutna cuantos objetos estamos creando con este codigo pero no me queda claro si 2 o 3, alguien me puede ayudar? muchas gracias!

```
Object a = null; 
Object b = new Object();
Object a = b;
```

Comment: Puedes leerte este post: [Definición y diferencia de objeto e instancia en Java](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/236373/107347)

Comment: tal cual esta tu codigo esta mal, porque no puedes definer `Object a` mas de una vez, eso es un error de compilacion el cual indicara que la variable ya existe. Suponiendo que deberia ser `a = b;` entonces estas declarando 2 variables las cuales apuntan a la misma instancia.

Comment: muchas gracias! ;)

Answer (score 1):

Se crea un objeto

```
Object a = null;
```

Define una **variable** a que apunta a un objeto. Pero no hay objeto, apunta a *null*.

```
Object b = new Object();
```

Vale, esto sí que crea un objeto y asigna la referencia a la variable *b*

```
Object a = b; // [SIC] Como ya te han explicado, conflicto de identificador de variable con la primera línea. Asumiremos que la primera línea no está.
```

Define una variable *a*, y hace que esa variable *a* apunte a la misma referencia que la variable *b*. **Pero ambas apuntan al mismo objeto**.

En general, para crear un objeto usas *new* (por supuesto, si llamas a un método que te devuelve un objeto ese método puede hacer el *new* internamente y devolverte el objeto).

Answer (score -1):

No soy experto en programación ni mucho menos, soy un estudiante al igual que tu, pero yo estudio python y c++, yo te digo que en ese cacho de código, null no lo podemos considerar ni un objeto ni un tipo por lo tanto estas creando 2 objetos uno de ellos sin valor asignado, es decir está vacío, otro con el valor "b".

PD: Esa es mi humilde opinión si me he confundido pido que me avisen de ello.

Comment: Yo creo que tambien dos pero no estoy seguro al 100%, muchas gracias por la respuesta! :)

Comment: Estás confundiendo **variables** (que apuntan a objetos) con los objetos propiamente dichos.

Comment: Ahora que lo dices tienes toda la razón, siento mi error.

Answer (score -1):

Mi opinión es que están creando dos, pero al final uno consume al otro y por todo queda solo un objeto, pero la respuesta es que se están creando dos objetos, el primero se inicia en null, el segundo se dice que es nuevo objeto y el tercer que iniciamos en null dice que será igual al segundo objeto. Por ello se inicia a en null porque después obtendrá valor del otro objeto.

Comment: *el primero se inicia en null* Eso no tiene ningún sentido. *null* no es un objeto. Y *a* y *b* son **variables**, no objetos.