# Como encadenar argumentos en función?

Tags: javascript

Quiero lograr en cadenar de algun modo los argumentos de una función de este modo :
`function suma(a)(b)(c)...{}`

y que retorne la suma de todos los valores. 
No se como se le llama a esto y no se como funciona. 
Agradecería si pudiese alguien explicarme o darme algun ejemplo por favor.
(A ser posible que sea lo mas plain js posible)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Si tienes algo como:

```
suma(1)(2)(3);
```

significa que suma(n) es una función que devuelve una función:

```
let fn = suma(1);
let fn2 = fn(2);
let fn3 = fn2(3);
```

Asumamos que para obtener el resultado final llamemos a la función sin parámetros:

```
fn3() === 6 //true
```

entonces tendremos que crear una función recursiva cuyo caso base es llamarla sin parámetros, mientras que el caso genérico sería llamarla con un parámetro que se suma:

```js
function suma(s) {
  return function clausura(n2) {
     if (n2 !== undefined) {
      s += n2;
      return clausura;
     }
     return s;
  }
}

console.log(suma(1)(2)(3)())
```

Te recomiendo leer sobre [las clausuras de función](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/607/c%C3%B3mo-funcionan-las-clausuras-en-javascript/236263#236263) para poder entender el funcionamiento de esta función recursiva con acumulador.

Por otro lado, podrías hacer algo mucho más simple con una función que admite diferentes cantidades de parámetros:

```js
function suma() {
  if (arguments.length == 0) {
    return 0;
  }
  let acc=0;
  for (let i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    acc+= arguments[i];
  }
  return acc;
}

console.log(suma(1, 2, 3));
console.log(suma(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10));
```

Answer (score 1):

Si lo que quieres es una función que retorne la suma de todos los valores de un `array`, utiliza la función nativa `reduce`de Javascript:

```js
let arr = [18, 85, 5, 35];
let res = arr.reduce((sum, el) => {
  return sum += el;
}, 0);
console.log(res);
```

Esta es una de las funcionalidades que puedes utilizar junto con `map` y `filter` que igual son más desconocidas pero van realmente bien para tratar `arrays`.
Te recomiendo la siguiente lectura:
https://medium.com/poka-techblog/simplify-your-javascript-use-map-reduce-and-filter-bd02c593cc2d

Comment: Lo que busco es que a una función se le puedan declarar los argumentos de esta manera: sum(arg1)(arg2)....(arg20) y retorne la suma de todos estos.

Comment: Podrías llegar a conseguirlo si hicieras una función que devolviese otra función y así poder llamarla con el numero parámetro, pero es mala práctica y no tiene sentido. Lo que escribí como código es lo más conciso y correcto que puedes hacer para sumar una serie de valores.