# ¿Como aplicar replace a un input text?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

Hola comunidad espero me puedan ayudar con este problema e antemano muchas gracias por su ayuda.

Tengo un json que se muestra abajo.

Ahora a un input text le agrego un valor de mi arreglo en este caso la posición 5 que es este "$ 80.50";

**¿Como puedo hacer un replace a ese input para quitarle el simbolo de pesos?** ya que en mi codigo me marca un error en la consola:

El input es un control html.

Gracias por su ayuda.

```js
 var col_detalle_subgrid = [{"Metrica":"Prom 1", "Costo":null, "Oferta":null, "Bono1":null, "Bono2":null, "Pago":"$ 80.50"},{"Metrica":"Prom 2", "Costo":null, "Oferta":null, "Bono1":null, "Bono2":null, "Pago":"$ 30.50"}];
 
 // Aqui declaro mi arreglo para llenarlo con los datos del json
 var arreglo_promo1= [];
 var arreglo_promo2= [];
 
 
 // Aqui recorro cada uno de los json 
 
 for (var i in col_detalle_subgrid) {
  for (var j in col_detalle_subgrid[i]) {
  
  // Hago una comparacion de los elementos del json
    if (col_detalle_subgrid[i][j] == "Prom 1") { 
    
    // Si la comparacion es correcta hago visible un Tab
      $("#Prom1").css("display", "inline-block"); 
      
      // Vuelvo a recorrer el json y lleno mi arreglo;
      $.each(col_detalle_subgrid[i], function(k, v) {
         arreglo_promo1.push(v);                                        
        });

    }
    else if (col_detalle_subgrid[i][j] == "Prom 2") {
    
      $("#Prom2").css("display", "inline-block");
       $.each(col_detalle_subgrid[i], function(k, v) {
         arreglo_promo2.push(v);                                        
        });

    }
   
  }

}


    //Fuera del for lleno mi input pero me marca error

$("#txtPromo1").val(arreglo_promo[5]) === undefined || $("#txtPromo1").val(arreglo_promo[5]) === null ? $("#txtPromo1").val(arreglo_promo[5]) : $("#txtPromo1").val(arreglo_promo[5].replace('$', ' ').trim());
  

 //Error en consola
 
 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of null
```

Comment: ¿Donde declaras la variable? ¿Esta dentro del [scope](https://medium.com/@sergiodxa/definiendo-conceptos-closure-y-scope-en-javascript-9081f1e113e6)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como te he puesto en el comentario, tu fallo no es otro que el `scope` de la variable. Tienes que tener en cuenta que si declaras la variable dentro de una función, no estará disponible fuera de ella.

Información respecto a los scopes:

- [Closure y scope en javascript](https://medium.com/@sergiodxa/definiendo-conceptos-closure-y-scope-en-javascript-9081f1e113e6)
- [Scopes of variables Javascript - StackOverflow Ingles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript)

También puedes aprender un poco mas de los tipos de variables y del uso de ellas con esta pregunta: [var/let/const y sus contextos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/106042/var-let-const-o-nada-en-javascript)

**EDIT despues de edicion del OP:**

Conclusion:

Fallo sintáctico o scopes

Demostración que el código es valido:

```js
 var col_detalle_subgrid = [{"Metrica":"Prom 1", "Costo":null, "Oferta":null, "Bono1":null, "Bono2":null, "Pago":"$ 80.50"},{"Metrica":"Prom 2", "Costo":null, "Oferta":null, "Bono1":null, "Bono2":null, "Pago":"$ 30.50"}];
 
 // Aqui declaro mi arreglo para llenarlo con los datos del json
 var arreglo_promo1= [];
 var arreglo_promo2= [];
 
 
 // Aqui recorro cada uno de los json 
 
 for (var i in col_detalle_subgrid) {
  for (var j in col_detalle_subgrid[i]) {
  
  // Hago una comparacion de los elementos del json
    if (col_detalle_subgrid[i][j] == "Prom 1") { 
    
    // Si la comparacion es correcta hago visible un Tab
      $("#Prom1").css("display", "inline-block"); 
      
      // Vuelvo a recorrer el json y lleno mi arreglo;
      $.each(col_detalle_subgrid[i], function(k, v) {
         arreglo_promo1.push(v);                                        
        });

    }
    else if (col_detalle_subgrid[i][j] == "Prom 2") {
    
      $("#Prom2").css("display", "inline-block");
       $.each(col_detalle_subgrid[i], function(k, v) {
         arreglo_promo2.push(v);                                        
        });

    }
   
  }

}


    //Fuera del for lleno mi input pero me marca error

$("#txtPromo1").val(arreglo_promo1[5]) === undefined || $("#txtPromo1").val(arreglo_promo1[5]) === null ? $("#txtPromo1").val(arreglo_promo1[5]) : $("#txtPromo1").val(arreglo_promo1[5].replace('$', ' ').trim());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="txtPromo1">
```

Comment: Hola @Parra  mi arreglo esta en la misma función posteriormente hago dos for  y lleno mi arreglo fuera de los dos bucles for lleno mis controles input. y me salta ese error.

Comment: @SHINOBI Si pones el contexto completo en el código puedo echarte una mano! Parece bastante claro que es problema de los scopes pero sin mas información no sabría decirte.

Comment: Hola @Parra ya he editado el código y lo coloque completo espero me puedas ayudar gracias.

Comment: Muchas gracias @Parra pero puede haber otra forma de hacerlo ya que no accedo a las keys del json porque estas pueden cambiar de nombre ya que trabajo con columnas dinamicas. He puesto los input dentro de los for y ya me muestra los valores pero no se si esto sea correcto.

Comment: @SHINOBI, Al final estas llamando a `arreglo_promo` pero arriba solo has declarado `arreglo_promo1` y `arreglo_promo2`. He modificado el snippet con tu codigo entero, y cambiado el `arreglo_promo` por `arreglo_promo2` y funciona, pero claro supongo que lo que quieres es sumar los 2 en 1 solo array, pero no veo donde se declara `arreglo_promo`

Comment: Hola @Parra te ofrezco una gran disculpa era arreglo_promo1 en lugar de arreglo_promo no verifique eso. Ya verifique que funciona tu código, lo tengo igual que tu y el mio aun me sigue botando el error en consola que raro seguire revisando cuidadosamente. Muchas Gracias.

Comment: si tenemos una respuesta de las [funciones de clausura](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/607/c%C3%B3mo-funcionan-las-clausuras-en-javascript)