# ¿Por qué no funciona el setTimeout dentro de este bloque if?

Tags: javascript, timeout

Este bloque forma parte de la validación de un formulario. Esta parte es donde luego de validar el formulario sin errores muestra un mensaje y después de 5 segundos redirecciona a otra página usando `setTimeout` y `window.location.href`. Funciona correctamente, solo que no lo hace tomando en cuenta los segundos indicados.

¿Dónde está el error?

```
const esExito = true;

if(esExito) {
    const dire = "wishlist.html";
    $form.className = 'oculto';
    document.querySelector('#exito').className = '';
    setTimeout(redireccionar(dire), 5000);
} 

function redireccionar(dire) {
    window.location.href = dire ;
}
```

Comment: puedes agregar todo el codigo de tus metodos?, parece que function redireccionar es parte del bloque if(es Exito)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No toma en cuenta los segundos indicados porque estas ejecutando la funcion `redireccionar(dire)`  el retorno es `undefined` cuando el timeout espera un tipo `function` colocare un ejemplo para que comprendas mas :

```js
function tal(dir){
  //codigo a ejecutar
}
console.log(typeof(tal()))
```

lo ideal es que tu funcion espere por parametro y retorne una función esto se conoce como [Clousure ó Clausuras](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/607/c%C3%B3mo-funcionan-las-clausuras-en-javascript) mira el siguiente ejemplo:

```js
console.log(typeof(redireccionar()))
setTimeout(redireccionar("av. siempre viva springfield"), 3000); 

function redireccionar(dire) {

    return () => console.log("direccion despues de los 3seg" ,dire) ;
}
```

Tu código quedaria de esta forma :

```
const esExito = true;

if(esExito) {
    const dire = "wishlist.html";
    $form.className = 'oculto';
    document.querySelector('#exito').className = '';
    setTimeout(redireccionar(dire), 5000);
} 

function redireccionar(dire) {
    return () => window.location.href = dire ;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Te recomiendo dejarlo de la siguiente manera, dada la [documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) de **setTimeOut** de **developer.mozilla.org**

```js
const esExito = true;

if(esExito) {  
    setTimeout(function(){
         redireccionar();
         }, 5000);
} 

function redireccionar() {
    alert('redireccion');
}
```

Saludos y escribe cualquier duda.

Comment: Yo no veo nada de JQUery en tu código

Comment: No estoy de acuerdo con esta respuesta, estás de acuerdo no te equivocaste?

Comment: Si, acabo de corregirlo, mil disculpas si confundí al receptor de la respuesta

Comment: cambia la documentacion a MSDN y estaria perfecta tu respuesta

Comment: @Aprendiz la pregunta es de jquery?

Comment: No @ Juan no lo es

Answer (score 4):

El problema es que estas llamando a la función con el método call (). Esto hace que la función sea llamada (se ejecute) en ese mismo instante. La solución es insertar la función dentro del setTimeout(una función anónima) o llamar a una referencia de esta función.

```js
const esExito = true;

if(esExito) {
    const dire = "wishlist.html";
    setTimeout(function() {
        alert("Hola")
}, 3000);
}
```

Comment: la respuesta valida y que explica el problema

Answer (score 1):

Estas agregando la funcion en tu mismo bloque de definicion de la primer funcion,
aqui agrego una correccion y ya esta probada.

```
  function redireccionar(dire) {
       console.log('action');
        return () => window.location.href = dire ;
    }

    function verificaExito(){
    const esExito = true;

    if(esExito) {
        const dire = "wishlist.html";
       // $form.className = 'oculto';
       // document.querySelector('#exito').className = '';
        setTimeout(redireccionar(dire), 5000);
    } 
    }
    verificaExito();
```