# duda con valor de variable cuando entra en bucle for

Tags: python

Como pone en el titulo tengo duda del valor de `num2`, vengo de java el caso es que ¿`res` no debería de estar declarada como atributo?

```
def num1(x):
    def num2(y):
        return x * y
    return num2

res = num1(10)
print(res(5))
```

Comment: Hola oshju, he corregido la identación y el formato del código, mira que esté tal como tu lo tienes para estar seguros. En cuanto a la duda, mencionas un ciclo `for`, pero en el código no hay ninguno ¿podrías aclarar ésto? `res` en ese código es una variable global sin más.

Comment: tu pregunta va a como funcionan las clausuras te recomiendo [leer esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/607/c%c3%b3mo-funcionan-las-clausuras-en-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

No teindria que estar declardo.
En python no se delaran las variables si eso es lo que preguntas.

Y lo que estas haciendo mas o menos es crear un generador en **res** que guarda el valor 10 dentro de **num2** y te devuelve el generador (la funcncion **num2** donde **x** = 10), mas tarde ejecutas la funcion generada que ahora esta dentro de **res**,

ejemplo:

```
res = num1(10)
```

en este caso res es igual a

```
def res(y):
    return 10 * y
```

Comment: en este caso la variable esta declarada en el parametro de entrada de la funcion creo que tu tambien deberias de leer como funcionan las clausuras