# Como declarar una variable dentro de una función y que no se reescriba JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, function

estoy intentando realizar una función que cada vez que se llame haga un array.push en una variable. Se que es una mala practica tener variables globales pero es la única forma que encuentro para no reescribir el array cada vez que llamo a la función. Ej:

```
function acumular(dato){
  let arr = [];
  arr.push(dato)
  return arr; 
}
acumular(2);
acumular(3);
```

hay forma de poner la variable dentro de la función y que no sobrescriba?
Muchas gracias

Comment: Porque no le pasas el array como parametro? Y devolves el array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se puede hacer con una [clausura](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/607/c%C3%B3mo-funcionan-las-clausuras-en-javascript/):

```js
function generadorFuncion(param) {
  //El contexto de la variable es la clausura de la función
  let variableOculta = 0;
  return function() {
  variableOculta++;
    console.log("Has llamado a la funcion",param, variableOculta, "veces");
  };
}

let funcA=generadorFuncion("a");
let funcB= generadorFuncion("b")

funcA();
funcA();
funcA();
funcB();
```

Answer (score 3):

No le veo mucho problema a usar una variable global para ese caso, pero bueno, te comento. Si defines la variable dentro de una función, obiamente cada vez que llames a la función resetearás la variable, en este caso perdiendo los valores acumulados.

Si no quieres usar una variable global, necesitas alguna forma de que la función recuerde el valor de la variable entre llamada y llamada, y la alternativa es hacerlo con una clase, y declarando la variable como una propiedad de la clase.

Para tu ejemplo, voy a hacer una clase Acumulador, que tendrá la propiedad arr, y un método acumular(dato) que irá metiendo en arr lo que reciba como parámetro. Quedaría así:

```
function Acumulador() {
    this.arr = [];

    this.acumular = function(dato) {
        this.arr.push(dato);
        
        return this.arr;
    };
}

var acumulador = new Acumulador();

acumulador.acumular(2);
acumulador.acumular(3);

alert(acumulador.arr); //Para comprobar
```