# Asincronismo con ciclos for en JavaScript

Tags: javascript, bucles, asincronismo

No entiendo el siguiente bloque de código: tengo entendido que `setTimeout` es asíncrono, por lo que el ciclo `for` se termina de ejecutar antes de los 1000 milisegundos, además de que la variable *i* declarada con `let` es local al ciclo `for`.
Entonces, según mi lógica, para cuando se ejecutan los callbacks, la variable *i* ya estaría fuera de su scope porque ya se terminó de ejecutar el ciclo `for`. Pero aún así funciona...
**¿Por qué?**

```js
function example() {
  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    setTimeout(function(){
      console.log(i);
    }, 1000);
  }
}
example();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se llama **clausura** (*closure* en inglés). Es cuando usas una variable en un bloque de código en la que no fue declarada pero aún así tiene visibilidad, es algo bastante útil para cosas como la que estás haciendo o para [hacer *currying*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currificaci%C3%B3n).
Por ejemplo:

```js
function suma(a,b) {
  return a + b;
}

function sumaN(n) { //devuelve/genera una función que suma n al parámetro que se le pase, usando clausuras
  return function (a) {
    return suma(a,n);
  }
}


const sumaSiete = sumaN(7);
console.log(sumaSiete(5));
```

Como curiosidad, me gustaría comentar que el código que has escrito funciona como funciona (una valor distinto para cada llamada a `setTimeout`) porque `i` está declarada con `let`: es una variable que sólo existe dentro del bucle for, por lo que se está creando una clausura nueva para cada iteración. Si hubieras usando `var` sólo habría una clausura porque la variable se consideraría declarada desde el inicio de la función `example`:

```js
function example() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    setTimeout(function(){
      console.log(i);
    }, 500);
  }
}
example();
```

Te remito a esta otra [pregunta/respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/607/c%C3%B3mo-funcionan-las-clausuras-en-javascript/236263#236263) para más detalles

Answer (score 1):

Eso funciona porque cuando haces el llamado a `setTimeout` estás creando una `función`, y esa `función` tiene acceso a la variable `i` del `for` (porque la función la estás creando dentro del ciclo).
Entonces mas adelante cuando esa función se ejecuta después (según el tiempo del `setTimeout`), se ejecuta con las variables a las que tenía acceso cuando se creó.

---

EDIT: Para responder la pregunta de los comentarios

Porque cuando se define la variable dentro del `for`, se crea esa variable dentro del ámbito de cada ciclo del for. Cuando la variable se define afuera, la variable es comun a todos los ciclos del `for`

Pongo 2 ejemplos

```js
//La variable referenciada dentro de la funcion es única
for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    setTimeout(() => console.log(i), 500);
}
```

```js
let i;
//La variable referenciada dentro de la funcion es "global" y se comparte por todos
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    setTimeout(() => console.log(i), 500);
}
```

Comment: @Mateo acabo de editar mi respuesta

Comment: Disculpa, creí que no ibas a mencionar lo de los comentarios. Repito la pregunta para que se entienda. Entonces, si la función sigue contando con acceso a la variable, ¿Por qué al llamarla no imprime el último valor que adquirió (3)?